# What is the most efficient way to convert a dataframe of dictionary values into a multi-index dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, multi-index

I have a dataframe (originally created from a list of dictionaries) that ultimately now has dictionaries containing data in each cell of the dataframe.  I would like to convert this into a multi-index dataframe (as per the illustration below) in the most efficient way possible.

Here is how far I am at the moment:

```
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

fruit_inventory_lst = []

fruit_inventory_lst.append({'Date':dt.datetime(2020,1,1),'Apple':{'Very Ripe':5},'Orange':{'Ripe':2}})
fruit_inventory_lst.append({'Date':dt.datetime(2020,1,2),'Apple':{'Very Ripe':10},'Banana':{'Not Ripe':3}})
fruit_inventory_lst.append({'Date':dt.datetime(2020,1,3),'Apple':{'Ripe':10},'Orange':{'Ripe':5}})

df = pd.DataFrame(fruit_inventory_lst).set_index('Date')

df >>>

             Apple              Orange               Banana
Date            
2020-01-01  {'Very Ripe': 5}    {'Ripe': 2}          NaN
2020-01-02  {'Very Ripe': 10}   NaN                  {'Not Ripe': 3}
2020-01-03  {'Ripe': 10}        {'Ripe': 5}          NaN
```

So the question is, how can I transform this specific type of dataframe (with a combination of dictionaries and np.nan values) into a multi-index dataframe in the most efficient manner?  The ultimate dataframe should be of the form illustrated below.  The main issue I am having is how to correctly construct the data such that I can input it into the below multi-index dataframe format (or is there a way to directly convert the above dataframe).

```
fruits = ['Apple','Orange','Banana']
headers = ['Ripeness','Quantity']
columns =  pd.MultiIndex.from_product([fruits,headers])
df_m = pd.DataFrame(data=np.nan,columns=columns,index=[df.index[0]])
df_m.index.name = 'Date'

df_m >>>

            Apple                   Orange                  Banana
            Ripeness    Quantity    Ripeness    Quantity    Ripeness    Quantity
Date                        
2020-01-01  NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
```

For clarity the desired output would be:

```
           Apple                Orange                  Banana
           Ripeness  Quantity   Ripeness    Quantity    Ripeness    Quantity
Date                        
2020-01-01 Very Ripe 5          Ripe        2           NaN         NaN
2020-01-02 Very Ripe 10         NaN         NaN         Not Ripe    3
2020-01-03 Ripe      10         Ripe        5           NaN         NaN
```

Thanks!...

Answer (score 0):

There maybe another ways. My approach for this problem would be first process the dictionary, So, that we'll have exact dictionary format for desired DataFrame Output

```
def seperate(data):
    new_data = []
    for i in data:
        item = {}
        for j in i.keys():
            if j == "Date":
                item['Date'] = i['Date']
            else:
                state = list(i[j].keys())[0]
                item[j+'_ripe'] = state
                item[j+'_Quantity'] = i[j][state]
        new_data.append(item)
    return new_data
df = pd.DataFrame(seperate(fruit_inventory_lst)).set_index('Date')
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks, but the output needs to be a multi-index dataframe of the form illustrated above.  Also very much trying to avoid explicit for loops.

Comment: you can just add list of columns to set_index() for multi-index. set_index(['Date','col1','col2']). And above mentioned approach is brute-force approach